# For all $t\in\mathbb{N}$, show that this sequence will eventually reach the number 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a_0=3,b_0=1$ and $t$ be an positive integer, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
a_n+2\cdot t\cdot b_n-1,  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
a_n/2, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

$$  b_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
 b_n+1,  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
b_n, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Now form the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by performing this operation repeatedly.

Note $a_0=3$ implies $a_1= a_0+2t-1=2t+2$.

Example: $t=1,(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(3,4,2,1,...)$

$t=2,(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(3,6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1,...)$ See $3\to^{+3}6\to^{/2}3\to^{+7}10\to^{/2}5\to^{+11}16\to^{/2}8\to^{/2}4\to^{/2}2\to^{/2}1\to\cdots$.

> Question: For every $t\in\mathbb{N},(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ will eventually reach the number 1?

The above claim is true for $t=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$. For $8$, not know is it reach at $1$ or reach infinity?

Source code python

```
def f(n):
    k=0
    while n > 1:
        print(n, end=' ')
        if (n % 2):
            k=k+t
            # n is odd
            n = n+2*k-1
        else:
            # n is even
            n = n//2
    print(1, end='')
 
t = int(input('Enter t: '))
n = 3
print('Sequence: ', end='')
f(n)
```

Comment: What is "k" in the above expression ? (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3934321/question-similar-to-collatz-conjecture (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: @Peter $a_{n_k}$ is k'th term in sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for exam in sequence $t=2,(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(3,6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1,...)$ so $(a_{n_k})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(a_{n_1},a_{n_2},...)=(3,3,5,1,...)$

Comment: @Peter, I think what the OP is really doing is defining a function $k(n)$, the number of odd entries among the first $n$ terms of the sequence, and then recursively defining $a_{n+1}$ to be $a_n+2tk(n)-1$ when $a_n$ is odd. (So $k(n)$ also has a recursive definition: $k(n+1)=k(n)+1$ if $a_{n+1}$ is odd and $k(n+1)=k(n)$ if $a_{n+1}$ is even.)

Comment: @lhf, this question is clearly related to the one you link to, but it looks different enough to stand by itself. (The OP would do well, though, to describe how they relate and differ, to provide some context for the question they're asking here.)

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks for your guidance, Post edited, please check